Get current colorscheme in lua
I'm trying to write a lua command that writes the current colorscheme out to a file. I can't seem to find a command that actually returns the name of the current colorscheme in lua, only one that prints that colorscheme to the command line.
Basically what i want is something like this;
local CurrentColor = vim.cmd.colorscheme()
-- ^^^ this doesn't work because vim.cmd.x returns nothing into lua env

except that it actually works.
I have been grepping around the helpfiles for the lua api, but so far I have found nothing helpful.

Welcome to [vi.se]!

The name of the color scheme will be stored in global variable colors_name (see :help g:colors_name), though it is possible that this variable will be unset when no colorscheme was explicitly loaded and the default is in use.
As such, you can get the name of the color scheme in Lua with the following expression:
local CurrentColor = vim.g.colors_name or 'default'

